# How do you make BWF(metadata) originator info what you want?

Tags: metadata, effects, library

Im using waveagent to deal with metadata and on the originator section it is labeled as either Fostex FR2-LE (my recorder) or Pro Tools (my DAW). How do I make this say what I want like my name (ShaunKellyFX: category). Also the originator reference has a crazy name like xy7eu5thuji? How can I make this say something like 01, 02.....

On waveagent it says the originator info is generated when converting a standard WAV to a BWF when is this happening so I can name it properly?

Comment: Found out how to do this. I use BWF MetaEdit. Its a free download at http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwfmetaedit/ just in case you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[MetadataTouch](http://www.digitalconfidence.com/MetadataTouch.html) can also do it.

> MetadataTouch™ is a powerful tool to view and edit metadata in
>   Microsoft Office® documents (Word, Excel®, and PowerPoint®),
>   OpenOffice™ documents, JPEG, JPEG 2000, AVI, MP3, MP4, F4V, WAV, AIFF,
>   PNG, SVG, APE, MPC, OFR, WV, TAK, and XMP files.

Comment: Great tip thanks for posting >> http://www.digitalconfidence.com/MetadataTouch.html

Answer (score 1):

remetacator.
does bulk as well